# How do I check the value of a field in a custom action in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In django admin, I want to check the value of a field in a custom action. In the below example i'm trying to do the following but this isn't retrieving the field name. How do I get the value of 'status' from the queryset?

```
if queryset.status != 'd':
```

Here's the full example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Article

def make_published(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if queryset.status != 'd':
        queryset.update(status='p')
make_published.short_description = "Mark selected stories as published"

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'status']
    ordering = ['title']
    actions = [make_published]

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object in the queryset might have a different status, so it doesn't make sense to get the status of the queryset.

If you loop through the queryset, you can get the status for each individual object.

```
for obj in queryset:
    status = obj.status
```

You could use `exclude()` to remove the objects with a particular status as follows:

```
def make_published(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset = queryset.objects.exclude(status='d')
    queryset.update(status='p')
make_published.short_description = "Mark selected stories as published"
```